# Does the Fetch Request do the recommended batch faulting?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm curious. Apple says in the docs:

> Core Data automatically fires faults
>   when necessary (when a persistent
>   property of a fault is accessed).
>   However, firing faults individually
>   can be inefficient, and there are
>   better strategies for getting data
>   from the persistent store (see “Batch
>   Faulting and Pre-fetching with the
>   SQLite Store”).

NSFetchRequest has this feature:

```
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
```

Is this essentially performing such a batch faulting like recommended?

*Just to make this clear for others, faulting does not mean "turning into a fault" but it means "materializing it", just like "making a Scooby-Doo out of it". Pretty ugly wording error, in my opinion, but it's at least consistent in the docs ;)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation answers that question, IMO:

> If you set a non-zero batch size, the
>   collection of objects returned when
>   the fetch is executed is broken into
>   batches. When the fetch is executed,
>   the entire request is evaluated and
>   the identities of all matching objects
>   recorded, but no more than batchSize
>   objects’ data will be fetched from the
>   persistent store at a time. The array
>   returned from executing the request
>   will be a proxy object that
>   transparently faults batches on
>   demand. (In database terms, this is an
>   in-memory cursor.)

That, to me, says that it divides the fetched results into batches that get faulted when any member of the batch is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch Faulting

Apple's batch faulting recommendation that you saw is about another case, not a fetch batch size.

Imagine you have a collection of faults, and you want to access their properties in a loop. A fault will be fired each time. So before iteration you execute a fetch request configured like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = ...;
NSArray *arrayOfFaults = @[faultOne, faultTwo, ...];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", arrayOfFaults];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

And not only does Core Data fetch all the data from persistent store and populates its internal cache (as a result of doing a fetch request), but also return the fully realized objects (because of `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO`).

### Relationship Pre-Fetching

Imagine you have `Department<-->>Employee` schema, and you just fetched all employees. Then you iterate them, and in each loop you get a department for an employee. Each time a department is accessed, relationship fault is fired. To avoid this, you configure the fetch request like this:

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"department"]];
```